# "Extending" Composable Functions

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In an app built with Kotlin and Android Jetpack Compose, let's say we use lots of  `TextField`s throughout the app. We want to wrap `TextField` in `StyledTextField`, customizing `color` and whatnot, and use this customized Composable throughout the app wherever we would need one, like so:

```
@Composable
fun StyledTextField(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    label: String = "SomeDefaultLabel",
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    // ...all the other arguments TextField accepts
) {
    TextField(
        modifier = modifier,
        label = {
            Text(
                label,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge
            )
        },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
            unfocusedLabelColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.someColor,
            unfocusedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.someOtherColor
        ),
        // Forward remaining arguments
    )
}
```

Is there any way to reduce the boilerplate of forwarding a dozen or two arguments from `StyledTextField` to the underlying `TextField`? Or am I thinking about app-wide custom Composables the wrong way entirely? It seems odd that Kotlin wouldn't have a way to "extend" a Composable, since it's all about reducing boilerplate.